# Laravel 7 Error message: 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: profiles.url

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sqlite, tinker

## **UPDATE: PROBLEM SOLVED!**

I'm refreshing my Laravel skills (using version 7.13.0), following the freecodecamp.org tutorial, here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE&t=11889s (1:21:49 to 1:22:50). When I get to the task of adding a profile manually with **php artisan tinker**, like I did on the frontend, it can not save. The database is sqlite.

THIS IS THE FULL ERROR:

> Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   profiles.url (SQL: insert into "profiles" ("title", "description",
>   "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Cool Title,
>   Description, 1, 2020-05-29 18:41:02, 2020-05-29 18:41:02))'

My function in **profiles_table.php** in database\migrations folder seems OK. It is this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('url')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');

        });
    }
```

The **Profile.php model** function is:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And the **User.php model** function is:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

So, in the terminal, after entering **php artisan tinker**, I filled in the following before it failed to save:

```
>>> $profile = new \App\Profile();
=> App\Profile {#3056}
>>> $profile->title = 'Cool Title';
=> "Cool Title"
>>> $profile->description = 'Description';
=> "Description"
>>> $profile->user_id = 1;
=> 1
>>> $profile->save();
```

**EDIT:** this is the controller file **ProfilesController.php**, if it helps to solve the problem:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfilesController extends Controller
{
    public function index($user)
    {
        $user = User::find($user);

        return view('home', [
            'user' => $user,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**All parts went OK, and after I typed the SAVE - it showed the error above.** Therefore I can't continue ahead to show the new profile made manualy.

I searched up Google and looked here for answers, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50782103/sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1048-laravel) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646976/php-error-in-laravel-while-inserting-data-via-sqlite). It didn't solve my problem, and others I think are not as relevant.

What should I do in order to fix it?

## Solution

Tanks to @mrhn, adding a new null table + installing `composer require doctrine/dbal` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37533819/12952748.

Comment: exit tinker, migrate the database again, enter tinker again and retry

Comment: It's worth noting that there's no problem with your code, I wasn't able to reproduce the error copy pasta

Comment: Try adding URL to the fillable array in the model.

Comment: Salim, I did the exit tinker and entering again, it didn't change. But what do you mean "no problem in the code"? Where to show somthing?
@TahaPaksu where to add a URL? in the profile controller return? Look up, I added it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your database does not allow the column `url` to be null. Your code is fine and nothing wrong with it, thou it seems you have maybe ran the migration and changed columns definition after.

In Laravel migrations only run once and secures the database has the same structure across systems. For getting the field nullable make a new migration.

```
php artisan make:migration url_nullable
```

For you new migration file, add the following migration. Which simply tells the migration to update `url` to be a `string` and `nullable`.

```
Schema::table('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('url')->nullable()->change();
});
```

After that run your migration and you database should be up to date.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I added a new nullable table like you suggested, but now it has trouble after typing "php artisan migrate" in the terminal - because of the existing profiles table. When if finishes the migrate is say says: 
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 table "profiles" already exists (SQL: create table "profiles" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "user_id" integer not null, "title" varchar null, "description" text null, "url" varchar null, "created_at" datetime null, "updated_at" datetime null))

Comment: You need to do Schema::table('profiles') you probably did Schema::create('profiles');

Comment: got it, thank you both! It works now, after also installing: composer require doctrine/dbal.
I got first an error, recommending to install it as it advises here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37533819/12952748